# How to show hidden div specific to dropdown selection?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

So I'm retrieving data/info from a JSON format. I have a drop-down list of names and when the user selects a name, the hidden info on that person will appear. The drop-down list is populated from the same JSON info/format.

I'm not sure what function I need to use to get the specific info for each person.

Here is a simplified jsfiddle link - 
https://jsfiddle.net/padzochambers/8036oebu/

```
.wrap {
  display: none; 
}
```

```
<select class="user_dropdown"> 
</select>

<div class="profile">
</div>
```

```
var data = [{
   "id": 1,
   "full_name": "Ignacius Antos",
   "email": "iantos0@jigsy.com",
   "password": "FK4umZJ9eh"
 }, 
 {
   "id": 2,
   "full_name": "Anallise Ousley",
   "email": "aousley1@yellowbook.com",
   "password": "5fLR4WhC"
 },
 {
   "id": 3,
   "full_name": "Norton Jenckes",
   "email": "njenckes2@de.vu",
   "password": "V24O3sl5nh"
 }
 ];

jQuery(function($) {
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    var profile_data = '';
    profile_data += '<option value="users">'+value.full_name+'</option>'; 
    $('.user_dropdown').append(profile_data);
  });
});  

jQuery(function($) {
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    var profile_data = '';
    profile_data += '<div class="wrap">'; <!--hidden div-->
    profile_data += '<div class="user">'+value.full_name+'</div>'; 
    profile_data += '<div class"user_info">'+value.email+' '+value.password+'</div>';
    profile_data += '</div>';
    $('.profile').append(profile_data);
  });
});
```

Hopefully, this is enough information. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    var profile_data = '';
    profile_data += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.full_name+'</option>'; 
    $('.user_dropdown').append(profile_data);

    var profile_data = '';
    profile_data += '<div class="wrap" data-id="'+value.id+'">';
    profile_data += '<div class="user">'+value.full_name+'</div>'; 
    profile_data += '<div class"user_info">'+value.email+' '+value.password+'</div>';
    profile_data += '</div>';
    $('.profile').append(profile_data);
  });
});

$('.user_dropdown').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
  $(".wrap").hide();
  $(".wrap[data-id='"+id+"']").show();
});
```

First I've changed the `value` of the `option` to `value="'+value.id+'"`

Second, I've added `data-id` to your `wrap` as in `<div class="wrap" data-id="'+value.id+'">'`

Now we use the `change` function to display the information.

**Demo**

```js
var data = [{
   "id": 1,
   "full_name": "Ignacius Antos",
   "email": "iantos0@jigsy.com",
   "password": "FK4umZJ9eh"
 }, 
 {
   "id": 2,
   "full_name": "Anallise Ousley",
   "email": "aousley1@yellowbook.com",
   "password": "5fLR4WhC"
 },
 {
   "id": 3,
   "full_name": "Norton Jenckes",
   "email": "njenckes2@de.vu",
   "password": "V24O3sl5nh"
 }
 ];
 
jQuery(function($) {
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    var profile_data = '';
    profile_data += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.full_name+'</option>'; 
    $('.user_dropdown').append(profile_data);
    
    var profile_data = '';
    profile_data += '<div class="wrap" data-id="'+value.id+'">';
    profile_data += '<div class="user">'+value.full_name+'</div>'; 
    profile_data += '<div class"user_info">'+value.email+' '+value.password+'</div>';
    profile_data += '</div>';
    $('.profile').append(profile_data);
  });
});

$('.user_dropdown').change(function() {
 var id = $(this).val();
  $(".wrap").hide();
  $(".wrap[data-id='"+id+"']").show();
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="user_dropdown">
</select>

<div class="profile">
</div>
```